# Why `where` produces a parse error inside list comprehension, but `let` doesn't?

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension, where-clause

Let's define a simple function called `func`:

```
func :: [Int] -> [Int]
```

I would like to use a `where` clause inside a list comprehension when defining this bogus function.

```
func xs = [ y where y = x + 1 | x <- xs]
```

Unfortunately, while trying to compile I get the following message:

```
parse error on input `where'
```

If I decide to use the `let` clause, everything works just fine:

```
func xs = [ let y = x + 1 in x | x <- xs] -- compilation successful
```

Why can't I use `where` like I originally intended to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you can see in the Haskell Report (https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/exps.html#list-comprehensions) list comprehensions take an expression in the left hand side. `let` is an expression, whereas `where` is part of top level declarations. Hence, it's not allowed there.

Answer (score 2):

This is because List comprehensions are equivalent to `do`-syntax.

To be clear, this:

```
[f a b q | a <- as, b <- bs, let q = a + b]
```

Is equivalent to:

```
do a <- as
   b <- bs
   let q = a + b
   return (f a b q)
```

And `let` expressions are permitted in `do`-blocks.

As for why `where` clauses aren't permitted, they're intended to provide a temporary scope in a top-level declaration.

Ie:

```
binding = la da fu gu
    where la a b c = c a b
          da = 6
          ...
```

In other words, `where` is only permitted after a variable has been described, and therefore is not correct in list comprehensions.